# The following circuit is said to be an AND circuit. Could you explain how?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pullup

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqbJsr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. What is the need for R3?
2. How does the following circuit ANDs the 2 signals X1 and X2? The output corresponding to case 2 and 3 in truth table fall under indeterminate LOGIC level of IC

Additional info:

1. Output is connected to the input pin of an IC(power sequencer) and it is an active high pin. Default state is floating
2. Truth table is derived based on simple circuit analysis

Comment: X1 and X2 would normally (for an AND circuit) be driven as either 0 or open (from an open drain / open collector device). If you re-do the table for that condition you will find it does the AND function. This circuit is also known as 'Wire-OR' (perhaps confusingly).

Comment: Redo your table with "0" and "open" for X1 and X2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the need for R3?

It may be required to pull the output up if/when the inputs are 'floating' (open-circuit). To understand its function we would need to know more about the circuit.

> How does the following circuit ANDs the 2 signals X1 and X2? The
>   output corresponding to case 2 and 3 in truth table fall under
>   indeterminate LOGIC level of IC

Whether the logic level is indeterminate depends on the IC. If you have its datasheet then you can find out what voltages are defined as 'high' and 'low'. Otherwise you just have to trust that the circuit has been properly designed.

I suspect that the inputs are not actually voltages, but [Open Collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) signals that pull down to ground when active. If this is the case then the output voltage will either be Vdd or close to 0, with no 'indeterminate' middle voltage.

Answer (score 0):

View this as a voltage divider.

If either "in" is low, a robust High" will not occur.

Only if both inputs are "high" will a robust "high" be output.

This gate depends upon accurate thresholding.

These circuits cannot be cascaded.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the last 2 sentences. Did you mean the resistor values have to be properly chosen to obtain the voltage levels within IC spec?

Answer (score 0):

That form of 'and' gate would usually be seen configured like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2vwf1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 'OR' equivalent would be as below:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOgsbwm.png)</sup>

Comment: "My, Grandma! What big diodes you have!" You can shrink your images by putting 'l', 'm' or 's' before the .png in the image link. You need to remove it if you want to edit the schematic.

Comment: Do you mean immediately before the dot of .png

Comment: Yes. Try it out. The effect is instant in the preview.

Comment: That is better.

Comment: Thanks Transistor.